# DB error on listing mailing recipients. Did anybody see that before?

Tags: core

When listing recipients of CiviMail either via advanced search or mailing report¹ I get a wrong row count query. See the where-clause in

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT contact_a.id) as rowCount  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   
LEFT JOIN civicrm_mailing_recipients ON civicrm_mailing_recipients.contact_id = contact_a.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_mailing ON civicrm_mailing.id = civicrm_mailing_recipients.mailing_id
WHERE  (  AND civicrm_mailing.id IN (2198) )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)
```

This is generated by `CRM\Contact\Bao\Query.php`.

Before I dig down into all the query generating code: Did anybody of you civi gurus out there see this before?

Relevant stacktrace is:

```
#10 /civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT count(DISTINCT contact_a.id) as rowCount  FROM civicrm_contact contact...")
#11 /civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(420): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT count(DISTINCT contact_a.id) as rowCount  FROM civicrm_contact contact...")
#12 /civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1496): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT count(DISTINCT contact_a.id) as rowCount  FROM civicrm_contact contact...", TRUE)
#13 /civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4977): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("SELECT count(DISTINCT contact_a.id) as rowCount  FROM civicrm_contact contact...")
#14 /civicrm/CRM/Contact/Selector.php(525): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(0, 0, NULL, TRUE)
#15 /civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(218): CRM_Contact_Selector->getTotalCount(4, NULL)
```

¹) URI on error is `/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?force=1&mailing_id=<MAILING_ID>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you getting has been now [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16534) and will be part of 5.23 release. You can either wait for 5.23 release and upgrade CiviCRM or apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16534.patch).

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: Do you know why I did not find an issue on issues.civicrm.org?

Comment: issue.civicrm.org is old. New issues are at https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues